# nodejs: Integrations of Google Fit into my application

Tags: node.js, google-api, google-fit

Is it possible to integrate Google Fit data into web application?

I am facing many complications to integrate with my web application?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible. Google Fit has a REST [API](https://developers.google.com/fit/rest/) for you to utilize.
You can make HTTP requests which will give you a response in JSON format; you can then use those JSON responses within your web application.

Comment: I order to get the step count I need to run many API's to get the data's.
1. dataSources
2. Sessions 

from the session I will from the datasets and then by using dataSources and datasets I will get the step count for a session only. Is their anyother way to get the data directly from the google fit.
Its like a big process to get the simple data.

Comment: Pretty much you are dealing with sensitive information so you will really need to gain authorization for your session first since you are connecting to Google's servers.

Comment: I have authorizations to access the google fit data.

Comment: https://www.googleapis.com/fitness/v1/users/me/sessions?startTime=2016-03-08T00:00:00.000Z&endTime=2016-03-09T00:00:00.000Z&access_token=*** by using this api I cant get these day sessions. Is their any other possible way to get the sessions. Some times it gets the data but some times not